# How much would cost to mine a block with Google Compute Engine?

Tags: mining-profitability, cpu-mining

Google has opened its Compute Engine and it has a [price list](https://cloud.google.com/pricing/compute-engine). How much would cost to mine a bitcoin block with Google Compute Engine?

Comment: I'm not going to crunch the numbers right now, but it wouldn't be worth it.  It would most likely take more than a year.

Comment: It's CPU only - I doubt it would be profitable.

Comment: They tell it's good to render videos. I wonder if a GPU farm wouldn't be much more cost efficient for that purpose too.

Answer (score 2):

Even if it was a GPGPU cluster, you will not make a profit from the prices they are charging. Mining at this point is only profitable with FPGA, ASICs and certain GPUs pending power consumption.

Comment: That's not what he asked.

Comment: @StevenRoose because the question suffered from the xy problem. He likely should have asked "is it profitable to mine with Google Compute Engine?".

Comment: @StevenRoose He asked a question that has a vacuous answer. I suspect his concern is what Lohoris pointed out. Is it profitable. I can pass the Turing test and infer meaning :)